# Extjs pop-up window support on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, extjs

I am trying to run an already present application on IE 9 but it has issues with the pop-up window and with .show() and .hide() commands.
i am getting a blue blank screen

The application is running smoothly on Chrome

The code on the Main Panel

```js
<% @page language = "java"
contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding = "UTF-8" %>
  < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < meta http - equiv = "Content-Type"
content = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
  < meta http - equiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
content = "IE=9" / >
  < script >
  Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
  });
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'lib');
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function() {

      /* var myMask2;
         myMask2 = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading Please wait..."}); */


      var basePanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            id: 'basePanel',
            frame: true,
            title: 'basePanel',
            width: 1500,
            height: 80,

            collapsible: true,
            layout: {
              type: 'table',
              columns: 1

            },
            defaults: {
              width: 100,
              labelWidth: 85
            },


            fieldDefaults: {
              labelAlign: 'right',
              msgTarget: 'side',
              margin: '0 0 5 0'
            },
            defaultType: 'textfield',

            items: [{
                  xtype: 'button',
                  text: 'clickToGetPopup',
                  id: 'clickToGetPopup',
                  disabled: true,
                  margin: '10 7 5 4',
                  width: 100,
                  handler: function() {

                      var i = 0;
                      if (Ext.getCmp("popupPanel") != undefined) {
                        Ext.getCmp("popupPanel").getStore().setProxy({
                              type: 'ajax',
                              method: 'Get',
                              url: 'lib/xyz.jsp
   reader: {
    root: '
                              topics ',
    totalProperty: '
                              totalCount '
   }
 });
 Ext.getCmp("popupPanel").getStore().loadPage(1);   
}  
popupPanel.popupWindow.show();
popupPanel.popupPanel.center();
 }
}]
});

Ext.define('
                              basePanel ', {
 singleton : true,
 basePanel : basePanel
});

 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The code on the pop-up window

```js
<% @page language = "java"
contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding = "UTF-8" %>

  <% @page import = "java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
  <% @page import = "java.util.Date" %>
  < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < meta http - equiv = "Content-Type"
content = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" >
  < meta http - equiv = "X-UA-Compatible"
content = "IE=9" / >
  < style >
  .myBold {
    font - weight: bold;
    font - size: 11px;
    color: #483D8B;
}

.mycol
{
  color:# 483D8B;
    font - weight: bold;
    font - size: 11px;
  }
  .btn {

    border: solid;
    border - color: black;
    background - color: #9EB32D;
background-image: none;
}



.x-grid-row .custom-column { 
    background-color: # D9D9D9;

  }
  .my - combo - lst.x - boundlist - item {
    font - size: 8px;
  }
  .x - boundlist - item {
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - form - field {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - form - text {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - field - form {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - form - focus {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - field - form - focus {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  }
  .x - field -
  default -form - focus {
    height: 14px;
    font - size: 10px;
  } < /style>

<script>


Ext.Loader.setConfig({
 enabled : true
});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', 'lib');
Ext.require([ '*' ]);


/ / definer For Grid
Ext.define('popupModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [{
      name: 'A'
    }, {
      name: 'B'
    }, {
      name: 'C'
    }, {
      name: 'D'
    },

  ],
  idProperty: 'ParentfromRTNWGridModel'
});





var popupStore = new Ext.data.Store({
  model: 'popupModel',
  pageSize: 20


});




Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.suspendLayouts();
  // add/remove items here


  Ext.QuickTips.init();


  Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext
    .create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

  var nwId = "";
  var nwVal = "";
  //var nwchangedVal = "";
  var nwIndex = "";
  var item = "";
  var CellEditingRTNW = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    pluginId: 'CellEditingRTNW',
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Editing',
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    editStyle: 'cell',
    autoCancel: false,

  });

  var flag1 = false;




  var popupPanel = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: 'popupPanel',
    store: popupStore,
    title: 'popupPanel ',
    autoScroll: true,
    columnLines: true,
    maximizable: true,
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',
      align: 'stretch'
    },
    hidden: true,
    plugins: [

      CellEditingRTNW,
      Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.Editing', {}),
      Ext.create('Ext.ux.ColumnAutoWidthPlugin', {})
    ],
    columns: [{
      text: 'A Column',
      width: 170,
      flex: 1,

      sortable: false,
      dataIndex: 'A',

    }, {
      text: 'B column',
      width: 170,
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      dataIndex: 'B',
      editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: storeCombo,
        autoLoad: false,
        hideTrigger: true,
        queryMode: 'remote',
        editable: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'name',
        selectOnFocus: true,
        d: 'popupEditor',
        listeners: {
          blur: function(e1, o) {
            console.log(e1);
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      text: 'C Column',
      width: 170,
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      dataIndex: 'Child_Name',
      tdCls: 'custom-column'
    }, {
      text: 'D Column',
      width: 170,
      flex: 1,
      sortable: false,
      dataIndex: 'Child_Value',
      tdCls: 'custom-column'
    }],
    viewConfig: {
      stripeRows: true,
      markDirty: false,
      enableTextSelection: true,
      displayInfo: true,
    }



  });



  var popupFilter = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    id: 'popupFilter',
    frame: true,
    //title :'popupFilter',
    collapsible: false,
    collapsed: false,
    buttonAlign: 'center',

    layout: {
      type: 'table',
      columns: 4,
      align: 'middle'

    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        align: 'left',
        width: 200,
        id: 'Parentidtoselect',
        columns: 2,
        items: [

          {
            boxLabel: '1',
            name: 'rb',
            width: '700',
            inputValue: '1',
            id: '1',
            listeners: {
              change: function(cb, nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                  1.show();
                  2.hide();

                }

              }
            }
          }, {
            boxLabel: '2',
            name: 'rb',
            width: '700',
            inputValue: '2',
            hidden: true,
            id: '2',
            listeners: {
              change: function(cb, nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                  2.show();
                  1.hide();

                }

              }

            }
          }

        ]
      },

      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Cancel',
        id: 'cancel',
        margin: '0 0 0 10',
        //colspan:2,
        width: 100,
        handler: function() {
          popupWindow.hide();
        }
      }
    ]


  });



  var popupWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    autoWidth: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    closable: true,
    constrainHeader: true,
    id: 'popupWindow',
    height: 550,
    width: 700,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    plain: true,
    stateful: false,
    title: '<div style="text-align:center;">popupWindow</div>',
    hidden: true,
    maximizable: true,
    layout: {
      type: 'vbox',

      align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
      popupFilter,
      popupPanel,
    ],

    listeners: {
      beforehide: function(panel) {}
    }

  });

  Ext.define('popupMainPanel', {
    singleton: true,
    popupWindow: popupWindow,
    flag1: flag1,
    popupPanel: popupPanel,
    popupFilter: popupFilter

  });
  Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
}); < /script>
</head >
< body >
  < /body>
</html >
```

Comment: This question is missing much information. What version of ExtJs, what is a 'blue blank screen'? And please include the code.

Comment: I am using ExtJs version 4.1.1.1 and a blue screen is an empty screen that doesn't show any panel,filters,etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about when you use Compatibility mode in IE9, what happens?  Does that help the scenario?  I am making an assumption from your wording that this was working else where, let me know if that is wrong.

What version of Ext JS is this?   Have you tried creating a Fiddle with this in order to test it against different library versions?   https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home

A little bit of code might help us, help you.

UPDATE:
So my first thought is that your using popupPanel as if its a JavaScript global variable but you have not set this variable yet in the top code.   You might want a `var popupPanel = Ext.getCmp("PopupPanel")` in there and then use that object in order to call those functions.  Now I see it in the code in the second window but I think closures are messing with you here in the first window.  I think someone with more experience will chime in at this point with my half answer out there now.

Also did you say this is working in other browsers but not in IE9? what other browsers did you test this on?  Or did you make code changes and now it just does not work at all?

Comment: I tried the compatibility mode with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> in the head section, but that doesn't help

Comment: I have tested this code on Chrome and there it works well,i get the pop-up window with all its elements(panel,filter).

Comment: I am confused how you got this working. for one I saw this when I ran it through a fiddle.   on the lines where you set your Proxy in your Reader you have  url: 'lib/xyz.jsp  but there is no closing single quote.  So is that a typo in the code your showing here? or in your original code too?  because how can you get it to run in Chrome with that miniscule missing piece?

Comment: This is a typo code, i have a complete application running on chrome. I faced issue with these pages so i just edited the code so that we get an idea what is going on and what my issue exactly is